# Prepare data befire RuleForEach in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to validate model which contains list of ids. There is few simple business rules like 'is it exists, is type is correct' and so on. I wanted to create internal Validator for single item (which is Id) but to avoid asking db for each of entity one by one I'm trying to get all of them and put on dictionary which later I want to pass to internal validators to get concrete entity by id.

```
RuleForEach(m => m.BunchOfIds)
    // how to get it?
    .SetValidator(new InternalValidator(_entities));
```

Any idea? I've tried to create CustomAsync but then I cannot use 'RuleForEach' but for now it looks like only possible option

Comment: I've tried also use 'MustAsync' which always pass but fill field with correct data, but 'SetValidator' is called before 'MustAsync' is executed so that data is not available there yet

Comment: You are fighting how FluentValidation works. You need data specific to your model, and yet the validator object is usually registered as a singleton in the application, shared amongst multiple models.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating 'inner models' but it seems I've to do that or prepare 'Context' which can be injected into validator